# "Neither Ana nor Bob can do every exercise but each can do some."

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I’m a bit confused as to how I should translate the following sentence:

> - Neither Ana nor Bob can do every exercise but each can do some.

I've identified the atomic sentences $A$ = Ana can do every exercise and $B$ = Bob can do every exercise, and managed to translate the first part into $(\sim A \;\& \sim B),$ but I don't know how to go about "each can do some".

Comment: My guess is it is expected you use the quantifiers "for all" and "for some" with respect to x can do exercise y. Like "not for all y A can do y" where A=Ana, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> - Neither Ana nor Bob can do every exercise but each can do some.

It's instructive to sequentially deconstruct the given sentence. The following are all equivalent to the above:

1. Observe that 'but' and 'and' have the same logical meaning.

   - Neither Ana nor Bob can do every exercise, **and** each can do some.
2. 'Neither M nor N passed' means 'both M and N failed'.

   - Ana cannot do every exercise **and** Bob cannot do every exercise **and** each can do some.
3. Be extra careful: it is tempting to mistranslate the first conjunct as "for every exercise $x,$ Ana cannot do $x$", which actually corresponds to
   'can't eat *any*thing', which has a different meaning from 'can't eat *every*thing'.

   - (It is not that Ana can do every exercise) **and** (it is not that Bob can do every exercise) **and** each can do some.

   These two pairs of parentheses are crucial delimiters, and mustn't be omitted.
4. Denote "Ana can do exercise $x$" and "Bob can do exercise $x$" by $Ax$ and $Bx,$ respectively. Notice that with this legend, the word 'each' in the above sentences will not be translated as 'for each'.

   - (It is not that Ana can do every exercise) **and** (it is not that Bob can do every exercise) **and** Ana can do some exercise **and** Bob can do some exercise.
   - (It is not that $∀x\,Ax$) **and** (it is not that $∀x\,Bx$) **and** $∃x\,Ax$ **and** $∃x\,Bx.$

   Symbolically rewrite the last sentence, optionally dropping all parentheses since quantification and negation have a higher precedence than conjunction & disjunction.

P.S. In step 2, 'neither M nor N passed' can alternatively be translated as 'it's not that (M or N passed)', noting that in logic 'or' is inclusive rather than exclusive.

P.P.S. In step 3, the difference is between $(∀x\,\lnot Ax)$ and $(\lnot∀x\,Ax).$

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use quantifiers. Hence, you might want to define $A(x)$ as "Anna can do exercise x" and $B(x)$ as "Bob can do exercise x".

The second part of your sentence can now be translated as $\exists x A(x) \wedge \exists y B(y).$ I will let you translate the first part.